# Solution of differential equation and then draw a graph

Tags: differential-equations, difference-equations, differential-geometry, finite-difference-method

I have two differential equations: 
$da/dt = a (.3 a^{-3} +  .7)^{1/2}$ and $d \tau /dt = 1/a$. The initial conditions are $t = 0$; $a = 1$ and $\tau = 0$, respectively.

How can I solve the equations in *Mathematica*? I need to calculate different values of $a$, $t$ and $\tau$ also plot $\tau$ vs $a$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @David :)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I solve the equations in Mathematica

One way could be to use `NDSolve`

```
ClearAll[a,t,tau];
ode1   = a'[t]   == a[t] Sqrt[ (3/10  * 1/a[t]^3 + 7/10)];
ode2   = tau'[t] == 1/a[t];
ic1    = a[0]    == 1;
ic2    = tau[0]  == 0;
sol    = NDSolve[{ode1,ode2,ic1,ic2},{a[t],tau[t]},{t,0,5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now you can plot them

```
 Plot[Evaluate[a[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[Evaluate[tau[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Is it possible to plot a[t] vs /tau?

You can try to use `ParametricPlot` for this.

```
 ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[a[t]], Evaluate[tau[t]]} /. sol, {t, 0, 0.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. But still now I found error when trying to draw a[t] vs /tau. Can you please resolve this?

Comment: Is it possible to plot a[t] vs /tau?

Comment: @Photon try  `ParametricPlot` to plot `a(t)` vs. `tau(t)`